# Can I use float to store millis function return value as done in the code?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

Can I use float data type to store the return value of millis function as shown on the code here? I saw unsigned int type to do it. But look I'm converting that millis to hour. That's why I'm trying to store in float.

```cpp
#include<Servo.h>
#include<math.h>
Servo mark1;
float dur = 2.30, del_dur = 0 ;
float sys_strt = (millis()/3600000), curr_tim = (millis()/3600000), del_strt = 0;
float inc_val;
const int relay_on = 8;

//2, output = 9;

void setup()

 {
          digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
          mark1.attach(9);
          mark1.write(110);//servo on
          Serial.begin(9600);
        //  pinMode(switch_on, INPUT);
         // pinMode(output, OUTPUT);
}


void loop()
 {
    if(Serial.available() > 0)
       { 
        inc_val = Serial.read();
        Serial.print("\n");
        
      if(inc_val == 'D') // D = DURATION
       {
        delay(2000); 
        dur = Serial.read();
        sys_strt = (millis()/3600000);
         //mark1.write(on);
        }
        
     else if(inc_val == 'd') // d = delay_duration_for_future_turn_on
       {
        mark1.write(158);// servo off
        delay(2000);
        del_dur = Serial.read();
        Serial.print("\n");
        delay (5000);
        dur = (Serial.read() + del_dur);
        del_strt = (curr_tim + del_dur);
        sys_strt = del_strt;
        //curr_tim = (millis()/1000);
            
        } 
 }  
     if((millis()/3600000) >= 5)
       {digitalWrite( 8, LOW);}
         
     if(((millis()/3600000) - del_strt) >= 0 && ((millis()/3600000) - del_strt) <=10 )    // statement for delay duration process
           {
            mark1.write(110);// servo on
            }
         
        
      if(((millis()/3600000)-sys_strt) >= dur)
           {
            mark1.write(158);//servo off
            }    
           
          }







    //int x = ((millis() / 1000) - off_timer_start) / 60;
 // if (digitalRead(switch_on) == HIGH) 
    //{
   // off_timer_start = (millis() / 1000);
    //digitalWrite(output, HIGH);
  //} 
   //else if (x >= offtime && digitalRead(output == HIGH)) {
    //digitalWrite(output, LOW);
 //}
  //delay(1000);
```

I was trying to store millis return value in float variable. But not sure whether it'll work or not.

Comment: What is `millis`?

Comment: Probably not. The first problem is not all numbers can be accurately represented in floating point. Second, in floating point, the point floats, so the bigger the count gets the less you can represent at the bottom. It wouldn't be too long before milliseconds weren't just hard to represent accurately, but impossible.

Comment: @NathanPierson number of milliseconds since start of program

Comment: `millis() / 1000 ->   long int / int -> long int` 
`millis() / 1000.0  -> long int / float -> float`
But there are some "mistakes" like `'del_strt'` and `'dur'` which results into some kind of ascii character and definitly not the del_strt variable

Comment: You can use `float` (or `double`) to represent time.  It will work just fine in many circumstances.  However (a) there are circumstances where it won't work and (b) it's rather unusual.  Most people use integers to represent time all of the time — and that's why this `millis()` function does, too.  So this is a case where, if nothing else, "When in Rome, do as the Romans do" probably applies.  Unless you have some specific reason (or you just love being contrary ☺), you might as well learn how to do timekeeping with integers, and get used to doing it that way.

Comment: Type `float` has 24 bits of precision.  So it will be able to represent 16777216 milliseconds (or 16777.216 seconds) perfectly accurately.  But that means that after about 4.7 hours, you won't be able to measure time with millisecond accuracy any more.  And after 19 days, you won't even to be able to measure time with tenth of a second accuracy.  (On the other hand, for this program, that might be perfectly acceptable.)

Comment: @SteveSummit I'm using float because I'm converting that millis return to hour which will surely result in a floating number

Comment: @RagibRownak That's fine.  But everywhere you divide by `3600000`, you'll want to divide by `3600000.` instead (that one little period is going to make a big difference!).

Comment: Also, rather than dividing by 3600000 all over the place, you might choose to write a little utility function `get_time_hours()` that you can then call, that does it for you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `float`, `millis()` return an `unsigned long` which is a 32-bit integer (i.e. equivalent to `uint32_t`).

Instead of doing division, which is more computationally intensive and has to be done in the runtime for thing like `millis()/3600000`, you could use `5*3600000` (which is a constant, and the compiler will optimize it to a constant of `18000000` during the compilation) for representing 5 hours. So instead of doing

```
if((millis()/3600000) >= 5) // do something
```

it can be done as:

```
if((millis() >= 5*3600000) // do something
```

or even better you could define the constant to make your code more readable as:

```
unsigned long fiveHour = 5*3600000;

if ((millis() >= fiveHour) // do something
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Arduino related **millis**() function returns **unsigned long**, so you cannot store it with full precision in a float.